# grive fails auth with exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl Gentoo

Tags: c++, google-app-engine, boost, google-drive-api

I used portage to install grive. It installs error free but when trying to use for the first time, it kicks back an exception.

```
gdrive # grive -a
-----------------------
Please go to this URL and get an authentication code:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Ffeeds%2F+https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.googleusercontent.com%2F+https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds%2&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&client_id=22314510474.apps.googleusercontent.com

-----------------------
Please input the authentication code here: 
4/CVoD_uotkiP6UVPO51JBkZFLSPmAdXZQzBkSuM55vk
Reading local directories
Synchronizing folders
exception: /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/grive-master/libgrive/src/protocol/AuthAgent.cc(174): Throw in function long int gr::AuthAgent::CheckHttpResponse(long int, const string&, const gr::http::Header&)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<gr::http::Error>
[gr::expt::BacktraceTag*] = #0 0x524b64 grive gr::Exception::Exception()
#1 0x505917 grive gr::http::Error::Error()
#2 0x50cd23 grive gr::AuthAgent::CheckHttpResponse(long, std::string const&, gr::http::Header const&)
#3 0x50c7db grive gr::AuthAgent::Get(std::string const&, gr::DataStream*, gr::http::Header const&)
#4 0x4ebc78 grive gr::v1::Drive::SyncFolders()
#5 0x4ec1da grive gr::v1::Drive::DetectChanges()
#6 0x4c981e grive Main(int, char**)
#7 0x4c9dca grive main
#8 0x7f61ae2cbb05 /lib64/libc.so.6 __libc_start_main
#9 0x4c8738 grive 

[gr::http::HttpResponseTag*] = 400
[gr::http::UrlTag*] = https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/-/folder?max-results=50&showroot=true
[gr::http::HeaderTag*] = Authorization: Bearer ya29.Ci8CA690emlxfHZzy2ZlVycWYAntDSmFEQTZNLgJV3CTb6OtoDHbgAiwqHG779h6mQ
GData-Version: 3.0
```

How do I connect to my grive following install?

Comment: Have you tried to go to that URL and get an authentication code?

Comment: @Adam yes, as indicated in the post, I post the key to the cli as required, and then that's when it dies.